# Embed font-awesome icon in Rails button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I would like to have a button as follow:

```
[ Sign in with FB]
```

where FB is a font-awesome icon. I tried the following, but couldn't figure out how to embed the icon to the button:

```
= button_to "Login with", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
```

Here is how `font-awesome` is normally invoked (in haml):

```
%i.icon-facebook-sign
```

How do I achieve the effect I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can [pass a block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) to `button_to` like so:

```
= button_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) do
    Login with
    %i.icon-facebook-sign
```

(Though I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use the Facebook icon itself as the button.)

Answer (score 4):

Add class option for button_to helper

```
= button_to "Login with", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class => 'icon-facebook-sign'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. I couldn't make this work. Could you expand your answer a little bit? I would like to know how exactly I can add class option for button_to, and after this change, why the call above will work. Thanks again.

Comment: its better explained here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: I thought you were suggesting to override button_to method. I tried your example and it didn't work. The icon won't show up. I think it makes sense, because we need image tag, together with class, and they must be placed in line with the text "Log in".

Comment: To summarize, for any html element generated using rails helpers, you can assign a class name to it using ':class' symbol.

Comment: Hi ranendra, I think this situation is an exception, because it involves embedding html tags back to a String. I believe your solution won't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

try this code, it runs for me

```
<%= button_to line_items_path(product_id: produit.id),class:"btn btn-outline-primary" do %>
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
<% end %>
```

just change the icon

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper method that uses the button tag but customizes the output:

```
#application_helper.rb

def button_to_with_icon(text, path, classes)
  form_tag path, :method => :post do
    button_tag(classes) do
      raw text
    end
  end
end
```

Then call the helper method with the raw html embedded as an argument:

```
<%= button_to_with_icon("login with <i class='fa fa-facebook-official'></i>", { action: "omniauth_authorize", controller: "users" }, class: "btn btn-info") %>
```

The action, controller, and class settings are just examples. But you can modify this to suit your needs, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the helper I made that works for me:

```ruby
def html_button_to(html = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil)
  button_to(options, html_options) do
    html
  end
end
```

Combined with the [font-awesome-rails gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails), it lets you do:

```ruby
html_button_to fa_icon(:facebook, text: "Login with"), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
```